# Including only ids where there is a 2 flags for one id (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called `df` and i want to subset the dataframe to only ids where there is a 1 and a 0 for the column `is_signup`. The following example would remove `id` = 1 because it only has a 1 (and not 0).

```
id   tag         is_signup
1    Button      1 
1    Circle      1
2    Button      1 
2    Circle      0
2    Diamond     1 
3    Circle      0
3    Button      1
```

expected output:

```
id   tag         is_signup
2    Button      1 
2    Circle      0
2    Diamond     1 
3    Circle      0
3    Button      1
```

How can I do this? I think a groupby would be helpful? but not sure how to formally do it

Comment: Just 1 and 0 since its a flag

Comment: Thanks , just clarifying :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a [**`groupby-filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) to check `is_signup.nunique()` directly:

```py
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.is_signup.nunique() == 2)

#    id      tag  is_signup
# 2   2   Button          1
# 3   2   Circle          0
# 4   2  Diamond          1
# 5   3   Circle          0
# 6   3   Button          1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since column `is_signup` a binary and can only have 2 possible values, we can `groupby+transform` with `nunique` here , then boolean index checking if the vaue is 2 (1 and 0):

```
df[df['is_signup'].groupby(df['id']).transform('nunique').eq(2)]
```

---

```
   id      tag  is_signup
2   2   Button          1
3   2   Circle          0
4   2  Diamond          1
5   3   Circle          0
6   3   Button          1
```